# How do terminal size changes get sent to command line applications though ssh or telnet?

Tags: linux, vim, ssh, terminal, telnet

How do terminal size changes get sent to command line applications through ssh or telnet?

1. A user connects to a remote machine with ssh or telnet.
2. They start editing a document in VIM.
3. Then they resize their terminal window.

The terminal must tell ssh/telnet that the window size had changed.  How does this happen?

ssh/telnet then uses its own particular method to send that change to sshd/telnetd.  What are these methods?

sshd/telnetd then tells the application that the terminal size has changed.  How is this done.  Is it the same method as from the terminal to ssh/telnet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the messy world of pseudo terminals.

Locally, when you resize your terminal your foreground process group gets a `SIGWINCH` and you can use `ioctl` to fetch the new size. But what does this have to do with the **remote** vim process ?

The subject is quite complicated but the gist of it is that the remove server (sshd) does this:

1. Opens a master psedoterminal device using [`posix_openpt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_openpt.html) (or `openpty`)
2. Forks a new child (typically this is bound to become a shell)
3. Severs its terminal connection using [`setsid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html)
4. Opens the terminal device (created in step 1) which becomes its controlling terminal
5. Replaces the standard descriptors (`STDIN_FILENO` and friends) with the fd from step 4

At this point anything the server process writes to the master side ends up as input to the slave side BUT **with a terminal line discipline** so the kernel does a bit of magic - like sending signals - when writing certain combinations, and you can also issue [`ioctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) calls with useful effects.

---

The best way to think about this is to explore the `openssh` suite.

- The client monitors for `SIGWINCH` - see `clientloop.c` and sets `received_window_change_signal = 1` when it receives it
- The function `client_check_window_change` checks that flag and **tells the server**:

  ```
  packet_start(SSH_CMSG_WINDOW_SIZE);
  packet_put_int((u_int)ws.ws_row);
  ...
  ```

So now the server should receive a packet which specifies a (potentially new) size.

- The server calls `pty_change_window_size` with the received sizes which does the real magic:

  ```
  struct winsize w;
  w.ws_row = row;
  ...
  (void) ioctl(ptyfd, TIOCSWINSZ, &w); /* This is it! */
  ```

This sets the new window size of the slave. If the new size differs from the old, the kernel **sends a `SIGWINCH` to the foreground process group** associated with that pty. Thus `vim` also gets that signal and can update its idea of the terminal size.

Comment: @chrisdew To be honest, when you asked I knew the main idea but didn't know the details, so I thought what better time to research it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to research and teaching all of us something with this good explanation!

Comment: Its really helpful for ssh, but what about telnet?

Comment: Very useful answer. Surprised by the small number of upvotes. Is there a way to check what the remote (ssh server) vs local (ssh client) process consider the size to be? For example a command to run on local and remote system that can tell you whether the "propagation" failed somehow (and remote is now mismatched with local).

Comment: I have discovered "tput lines" and "tput cols" for remote side.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the terminal window generates a [`SIGWINCH`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch18lev1sec12.html) signal.

See also the related [glibc documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_478.html).